# Insert div at Specific Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, insert

I am a beginner in jquery and trying to make changes in existing code. I would like to insert `div` containing some JS at specific index.

```
<div id="test1"> <!-- JS code--> </div>
```

The existing code inserts this `test1` div at `<a name='more'></a>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#test1').appendTo(jQuery('a[name="more"]'));
    });
</script>
```

This code works perfectly but 
I Wish to insert the div at 2 different indexes which i will generate in runtime. Let's say, i wish to insert div at  **50th ,100th** location or index.

I have tried

```
jQuery('#test1').insertAfter($(this).children().eq(50));
jQuery('#test1').insertAfter($(this).children().eq(100));
```

but doesn't work. I wonder if it's even possible or not? The HTML is simple consisting div,img,br. There are no tables in the markup.

P.S. The indexes have been calculated considering appending don't break the html.

Comment: Please show some of your markup (html). What kind of elements are being created? Table row elements work differently from DIVs, etc.

Comment: @gibberish: It's a simple blog post so any normal HTML should do. There will be divs,img,br etc. There are no tables for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your set of elements, reduce to the one you want with `.eq()` and use `.after()` to append. See: http://jsfiddle.net/YPvDf/  for a working example based around this code:

```
<div id="blah">
  <p>How now</p>
  <p>How now</p>
  <p>How now</p>
  <p>How now</p>
  <p>How now</p>
  <p>How now</p>
</div>
<button id="aButton">Click me</button>
jQuery('#aButton').click(function () {
  jQuery('#blah p').eq(3).after('<p>Brown Cow</p>');
});
```

Also remember that the element set is zero-indexed, so use `.eq(49)` to insert after the 50th element and so on.

**Updated** Having clarified  your needs, here's some code that does what I think you want (same HTML as above):

```
jQuery('#aButton').click(function () {
  var stuff = jQuery('#blah').html();
  var splitIndex = 31;
  var myString = '<span> Brown Cow! </span>';
  var beforeString = stuff.substring(0,splitIndex);
  var afterString = stuff.substring(splitIndex);
  jQuery('#blah').html(beforeString + myString + afterString);
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uKgwU/

If not, then sorry... try to be more clear in your question next time!

Comment: Your answer is about element index. I was looking for answer related html-text  Index. Any way to add it after 20th character in HTML markup?

Comment: Sure, get the HTML as a string, then use one of the substring methods to break apart into two "before" and "after" your desired index strings, then concatenate `beforeString + yourString + afterString` and reinsert.

Comment: Updated answer for you. Given both examples, you should be able to do what you want if the 2nd isn't exactly it.